# Database state with cordova/phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

If i create database using cordova like this `var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);`

Will this database save when my application will be closed, and how do i prevent it from creating everytime when i launch my app ?

Answer (score 1):

> Will this database save when my application will be closed

Yes, when you close your application you can still access the data in the database after restart (data will be persisted).

> and how do i prevent it from creating everytime when i launch my app

The openDatabase method creates the database object either using existing database or creating new one (if there is already a database called "Cordova Demo" you'll get it instead of creating a new one).

Comment: Where can i find database file?
I tried to create some records, then restart application and then tried to access them, but had no luck

Comment: take a look at that nice tutorial: http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/